# How to type in Laravel Dusk with an array of input text?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I have these array of input text :

```
<input type="text" name="amount[0]">
<input type="text" name="amount[1]">
<input type="text" name="amount[2]">
<input type="text" name="amount[3]">
```

and I want to type a value using Laravel Dusk. I can't just hardcode using :

```
$browser->visit('/create')
    ->type('amount[0]', '100')
    ->type('amount[1]', '100')
    ->type('amount[2]', '100')
    ->type('amount[3]', '100');
```

because the number of input fields depends on the number of items in the database.

I tried using :

```
$browser->visit('/create')
    ->type('amount[]', '100');
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the inputs with a CSS selector:

```
$inputs = $browser->elements('input[name^="amount["]');

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    $input->sendKeys('100');
}
```